# Android progressbar set different background drawable on progress 0 and progress 100

Tags: android, kotlin, android-view, android-drawable, android-progressbar

I am trying to implement a circular download progress bar which can show different drawable

- when the progress is 0(download not started)
- when the progress is > 0 && < 100 (download in progress)
- when the progress is 100(download complete)

I was able to implement the showing of circular progress bar when the progress is > 0 && < 100
with the below code

circle.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape
            android:shape="ring"
            android:thicknessRatio="16"
            android:useLevel="false">
            <solid android:color="#DDD" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="270"
            android:toDegrees="270">
            <shape
                android:shape="ring"
                android:thicknessRatio="16"
                android:useLevel="true">
                <gradient
                    android:endColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:startColor="@color/colorAccent"
                    android:type="sweep" />
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
        style="@style/CircularDeterminateProgressBar"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:progress="60" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view_progress"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/progress_bar"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/progress_bar"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/progress_bar"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/progress_bar"
        tools:text="60%" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_decr"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="- 10%"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/progress_bar"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/progress_bar" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_incr"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="+ 10%"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/progress_bar"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/progress_bar" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

and my activity as below

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private var progr = 0
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        updateProgressBar()
        button_incr.setOnClickListener {
            if (progr <= 90) {
                progr += 10
                updateProgressBar()
            }
        }
        button_decr.setOnClickListener {
            if (progr >= 10) {
                progr -= 10
                updateProgressBar()
            }
        }
    }
    private fun updateProgressBar() {
        progress_bar.progress = progr
        text_view_progress.text = "$progr%"
    }
}
```

I am not sure how to set a different drawable(download icon) when the download progress is 0 (not started) and other different drawable(download complete icon) when the download progress is 100.

Any pointers or solution would be really helpful?

Answer (score -1):

**Solution 1** : Use a LevelListDrawable. You will be able to define the different drawables to be used for different levels.

```
 <level-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:maxLevel="0" android:drawable="@drawable/ic_wifi_signal_1" />
  <item android:maxLevel="1" android:drawable="@drawable/ic_wifi_signal_2" />
  <item android:maxLevel="2" android:drawable="@drawable/ic_wifi_signal_3" />
  <item android:maxLevel="3" android:drawable="@drawable/ic_wifi_signal_4" />
 </level-list>
```

Documentation :

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/LevelListDrawable

**Solution 2** : Update the drawable dynamically using ProgressBar.setIndeterminateDrawable() whenever you update the progress bar level.

Documentation :

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar#setIndeterminateDrawable(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)